# I wanted to retrieve my imagelist from database

Tags: php

I wanted to retrieve my images from database, but the image caption only appears and the real image doesn't appear yet they successfully stored in the database., below is my code

```
<?php include('config.php'); 
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM photos"); 
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
  echo '<div id="imagelist">'; 
  echo '<p><img src="'.$row['location'].'"></p>'; 
  echo '<p id="caption">'.$row['caption'].' </p>'; 
  echo '</div>'; 
} ?>
```

Comment: <?php
include('config.php');
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM photos");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
echo '<div id="imagelist">';
echo '<p><img src="'.$row['location'].'"></p>';
echo '<p id="caption">'.$row['caption'].' </p>';
echo '</div>';
}
?>

Comment: just edit your question, ok?

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: check if the location address is correct - if it is relative path, it will depend upon where you call that script.

Comment: do you store the image in the database (blob-field), or store the image in a folder and the location in the database?

Comment: also change the naming convention - what you wrote will give you multiple `<div>` and `<p>` elements with the same id, which is forbidden. You can use class instead, with the same name, `imagelist` and `caption`